# Скорость цикла begin() end() STL контейнеров

Tags: stl, c++

Есть где-нибудь таблица или информация об этом?

Не могу что-то найти, нужно точно знать, будет ли сложность N, log N, C и т.д. для цикла прохода:

```
for(auto IT = cont.begin(); IT != cont.end(); IT++){}

List
Deque
Vector
set
multiset
map
multimap
stack
queue
priority_queue
slist
```

Вот примерно как тут:
https://www.unetti.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Screen-Shot-2013-03-21-at-11.31.09-AM.png

Comment: O(N)
А теперь позвольте задать вопрос. Как именно вы представляете себе итерирование за logN? За константное время? И самый глдавный - что такое по вашему "сложность" в O-нотации?


Comment: "Как именно вы представляете себе итерирование за logN?"
Это просто пример, как в той ссылке. Я не знаю, как контейнеры устроены, вдруг обход какого-то контейнера может быть дорогой операцией.

"И самый главный - что такое по вашему "сложность" в O-нотации?"
Что конкретно рассказать?

1) Вообще все за O(N)? То есть обход через begin() end() по std::map будет таким же по скорости, как проход по std::vector, и разницы какой контейнер нет абсолютной для обхода?

2) Помимо сложности алгоритма, интересует еще и как это реализовано с учётом оптимизации при компиляции, или везде всё одинаково быстро

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Быстрее, чем за O(N) никак не получится. Никак. В любом случае нужно перебирать все элементы. Поэтому конечная сложность будет O(N) * (сложность инкремента итератора).

Обсудим сложность инкремента итератора.

`stack`, `queue`, `priority_queue` - для этих контейнеров нет смысла обсуждать сложность - у них нет нужного итератора.

`vector` - тут все просто. так как вектор храниться единым массивом, то процедура инкремента итератора - это просто приплюсовать число.

`list` - обычно реализовывается как цепочка с блоков, которые указывают на следующий. Поэтому в прямом направлении проход быстрый (это просто взятие указателя, чуточку медленнее, чем приплюсовать число, так как нужно читать с памяти). Сложность инкремента итератора - константная.

`deque` - может быть реализовано на базе vector или list. Соответственно, на это и нужно ориентироваться.

`slist` - в стандартной библиотеке такого класса нет. Но обычно он реализуется либо на базе вектора, либо списка. Поэтому, скорее всего сложность инкремента итератора будет константной.

`set`, `multiset`, `map`, `multimap` - с этими типами нужно копать глубже в конкретную реализацию конкретного компилятора. Тут я написал простенький код, который просто считал время итерирования и делил на общее кол-во элементов. (я тестил на gcc version 4.9.2 20141101 (Red Hat 4.9.2-1) (GCC), fedora 21). У меня получилось, что время инкрементирования итератора приблизительно константно.

Итого, для `stack`, `queue`, `priority_queue` указанный в вопросе цикл не работает (у них нет подходящих итераторов), для slist нужно смотреть в конкретную реализацию. Для всех остальных сложность, как не удивительно O(N).

Comment: @KoVadim, из http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set

    Sets are typically implemented as binary search trees.

Думаю, это же относится и к map (но не обязательно к unordered\_set/unordered\_map они м.б. хэш-таблицами).

Если это так (и элементы не провязаны в список (а в это я практически не верю)), то время обхода всего контейнера будет O(N) \* log(N).

Понятно, что столь малый довесок (log(N) / N) на один шаг итератора не уловить.

Comment: я тестил не на десяти элементах, а на десятках и сотнях тысяч. Время было константно (в пересчете на итерацию).

Классическая бинарная куча реализовывается в виде массива и ее итерировать можно как массив. Поэтому, я сильно сомневаюсь, что там будет O(N*log(N)).

Логарифм это хороший довесок. Так что заметить его можно.

Comment: Да, я сам уже понял, что не прав. На самом-то деле обход дерева занимает O(N). Листья же мы посещаем по одному разу, а остальные узлы по 3(иногда м.б. 2) раза.

--

Интересно, как у них все это устроено? Узлы содержат указатель  не родителя или итератор "тащит" в себе список родителей?

Comment: узлы посещаются по одному разу. Посмотрите в википедию, что такое [двоичная куча](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0).

Comment: @KoVadim, причем здесь двоичная куча (она же пирамида)?

Чтобы не быть голословным (это же STL) смотрим сорсы, например, /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/set и в /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h видим rb-tree с указателем на родителя в узлах.

Comment: значит на дереве реализовано. Просто можно и кучей реализовать. Все равно сложность выходит константная.